# Creating a simple airplane reservation program program will not start over

Tags: c

This is the code that I have. Currently the code prints out all the seats at once. I need it to print one seat and then restart to the user prompt. it can not assign the same seat and should show first class full when there are no more seats.

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

```
int firstClass[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; //first class array
int firstLen = 4; // first class length
int userInput;
int i;

//user prompt
printf("Please type 1 for First Class\n");
printf("Please type 2 for Economy\n");
printf("Please type 0 to Quit\n");
printf("\n");
scanf("%d", &userInput); // scanning for user input

 
if(userInput = 1){
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if(i < firstLen){
            printf("Class: First     Seat Number: %d\n", firstClass[i]);
            
        }
        else{
            printf("First Class Full. Next flight is tomorrow.");
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you need a loop (for or while)

Comment: As a general observation, there's far too many magic numbers (hard-coded constants) in this program. You already have two arrays with seat numbers and a length for each. You should build your loops around those, instead of repeating the contents of the arrays. Right now, if you modify the plane configuration, you have to also modify your input loops. This kind of dependency where the code knows too much about the data is a very common source of bugs.

Comment: `for(i = 1; i < 5; i++)` is beaking the array `firstClass[]` which has 4 elements. So `for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)`. Arrays are indexed from 0.

Comment: And `economyclass[i]` is not indexed correctly with `for(i = 5; i < 13; i++)`. It can be indexed from `[0]` to `[7]`. The out-of-range indexing might be scrambling other variables, or anything.

Comment: You should also remove the `return` statements from your loops, as it will exit your `main` function before looping through all of the items.

Comment: I adjusted the code to just a portion of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can track which seats are taken with a variable. Each time a user selects `1` print out the seat number for that index, and then increment the index.

You'll then wrap this in a loop (`for` or `while`) and only exit the loop when the user enters `0`. Make sure you define the variable used to track the current index *outside* of the loop.

Something like this:

```
int main(void)  
{
    const int first_class[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    const size_t first_class_size = sizeof(first_class) / sizeof(first_class[0]); 

    size_t first_class_index = 0;
    int user_input = 0;

    do
    {
        print_menu();
        scanf("%d", &user_input);

        if (user_input == 1) 
        {
            if (first_class_index < first_class_size) 
            {
                printf("Here is your ticket information:\n");
                printf("Seat Number: %d, Class: First\n\n", first_class[first_class_index++]);
                continue;
            }
            printf("No first class seats are available.\n\n");
        }
    } while(user_input != 0); 
}
```